# Laravel migration works in strange way

Tags: mysql, laravel

I've dropped my test database then I want to create new database using saved migrations:

```
2017_03_01_000000_create_api_table.php
2017_03_06_000000_create_beeline_calls.php
2017_03_13_000000_modify_beeline_emails.php
2017_03_14_000000_interactive_forms.php
2017_03_16_000000_model_instances.php
2017_03_24_000000_create_objects.php
2017_03_24_000001_create_objects_tables_v2.php
2017_03_24_000003_make_comments_without_users.php
2017_03_27_000000_add_processed_to_announcements.php
2017_03_29_000000_create_ads_channels.php
2017_03_29_000001_announcement_client.php
2017_04_06_000000_create_filters.php
2017_04_07_000000_create_new_input_types.php
```

When I run `php artisan migrate --pretend`

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                                                                  
  There is no column with name 'creator_id' on table 'application_model_instance_announcement_comments'.
```

But first migration file to run is `2017_03_01_000000_create_api_table.php`

Why does it run not from start? Database is empty, `migrations` table is empty.
As I understand Laravel should run migration files in alphabetical order.

Comment: php artisan migrate:refresh --seed try thin one

Comment: `migrate` did not work, but `migrate:refresh` did. I do not understand why...

Comment: i think migrate refresh has also some of these commands that i have in my anser and it deletes all migrations and data in your DB tables....so that is why it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to perform `php artisan migrate` that table where you are creating the columns can't contain the same column names as in that migration. You must delete it first and with this command

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

you are doing exactly this

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
php artisan migrate
```

There are 2 commands in `php artisan migrate:refresh`

When changing something in migrations always run these commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

It will clear all old stuff and should run smoothly!

Comment: Sorry, but for some strange reason it did not help. `migrate:refresh` helped.

Comment: yes because in migrate refresh there are 2 commands actually... `php artisan migrate:rollback` and `php artisan migrate` i will update my answer